# I converted a string into float, how can I validate that is a f64?

Tags: rust, struct, enums

I have a really weird doubt.

I'm following the rust programming book and in a chapter for practice purpose they suggest to do a temperature converter... I actually did it, the thing is that I don't understand why works.

The main problem comes when I tried to replicate a segment of the code that allows me to compare if the value that the user introduced is a float type.

When I took that code and i try to compiled i get the next error.

```
Compiling enums v0.1.0 (C:\Users\ruben\Proyectos\Rust\the_rust_programming_language\enums)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\main.rs:96:35
   |
96 |           Err(parse_float_error) => {
   |  ___________________________________^
97 | |             println!("Please input a valid value. _{}_", parse_float_error);
98 | |         }
   | |_________^ expected `f64`, found `()`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `enums` due to previous error
```

This is the code that generate the error:

```
use std::io;

fn user_input() -> String {
    let mut user_input: String = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut user_input)
        .expect("Failed to read line");
    return user_input;
}
fn main() {
    let fahrenheit: f64 = match user_input().trim().parse() {
        Ok(f64) => f64,
        Err(parse_float_error) => {
            println!("Please input a valid value. _{}_", parse_float_error);
        }
    };
}
```

[The working full version of the temperature converter could be find here](https://github.com/rubenVillalvazo/temperature_converter/blob/master/src/main.rs)

***The most probable is that must to have a better way to build that code, so if some of you have suggestions I would be happy to read it.***

I understand that the problem comes for the type `enum`, the thing is that I really don get how the `enums` works.

To me, in a simple way, the `enum` is used when a piece of data is one kind or another from the available in the `enum`, and I get an example that helped me to understand it in that way: [Enums](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/custom_types/enum.html#enums). The thing is that i really, really don't understand it and the book doesn't help.

I know that it is a very general question, but if someone have a north to follow it would help a lot.

Thank You.

Comment: I don't think your problem is with understanding enums, but with understanding `!`, which is the type of `return` and `continue` expressions like [here](https://github.com/rubenVillalvazo/temperature_converter/blob/master/src/main.rs#L53). The closest you get to an explanation in the book is [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/error/result/early_returns.html). (Also, aaaaaa @ naming a variable `f64`. I would find the example less confusing if it was `Ok(val) => val,`. Maybe not the best learning example.)

Comment: I actually read that before, and I didn't think that the error could be a early return, actually I followed a previous exercise of the book to do the `.parse()` conversion and the `match` expression,  in the example the `.parse()` conversion returned a `num` result, and in my mind a `f64` result maked sense, I would be careful with that in the future, thank @Caesar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To me, in a simple way, the enum is used when a piece of data is one kind or another from the available in the enum

Mostly right, an enum can have one or more variants and each of those variants can (but does not have to) have associated data. The type of the data for each variant can be the same or different.

The `result` enum specifically has two variants. The `Ok` variant indicates that the operation was successful. The `Err` variant indicates that there was an error. `result` is a generic type, it has two type parameters, `T` representing the type of the expected result and `E` representing the type of the error.

It's worth noting at this point that the way types are inferred in rust is very different from C, C++ and many other popular languages. The process of determining types for an expression in C/C++ flows outwards from the innermost parts of the expression. Each function call or operator is chosen based on the types of it's arguments and that determines the type of it's result, which in turn becomes an argument to the next step outwards. In Rust by contrast type inference can run in both directions. The types in an expression can be, and often are, inferred from what you do with the result.

A match expression lets you break down an enum and take different actions based on what variant you have.

---

With all that in mind lets break down your code.

```
let fahrenheit: f64 =
```

We declare a variable called `fahrenheit` and we explicitly tell the compiler it's type. This type will drive type checking and inference as the compiler tries to interpret the expression.

```
match
```

We begin our match expression.

```
user_input()
```

We call a function, said function is not generic in any way, so that gives the compiler another type, `String` to work with.

```
.trim()
```

We call the trim method on the String. Again this is not generic in any way, so we again have a fixed type `&str`.

```
.parse()
```

Now here is where things get more interesting, "parse" is a generic function. It returns a `result` but the generic parameters of `result` are not fixed, they will have to be inferred from what the user does with the result and the restrictions in the signature of `parse`.

```
    Ok(f64) => f64,
```

If the result is `Ok` we unwrap the value and return it. The use of `f64` here is somewhat unfortunate, it looks like a type name but it's actually more like a variable name. Your code would behave the same and be more idiomatic if you had written `Ok(v) => v,`

In any case, this part of the expression lets the type inference complete it's work. You have matched on the `Ok` variant and treated the result as an f64. So `T` must be `f64`. Combining that with the signature of `parse` and the implementation of `FromStr` for `f64` means that `E` must be `ParseFloatError`.

```
    Err(parse_float_error) => {
        println!("Please input a valid value. _{}_", parse_float_error);
    }
```

And this is where we go wrong. We have printed an error message but we haven't actually handled the error! We still have an expression that expects a f64 and we don't have one! We need to handle the error in a way that either gives us a valid f64, or promises the compiler that it won't need one.

There are a few ways you could do that.

- You could pick a default value (as in Paul's answer) `0.0f64`
- You could panic `panic!("foo {}",parse_float_error)`
- You could call a function that promises to never return normally for example `abort()`
- You could return from the function `return`
- If your code was inside a loop, you could use the loop control constructs `break` or `continue`
- If you are absoloutely positive that errors will never happen you can tell the compiler that they will never happen. If you tell the compiler that something will never happen and it happens anyway that is undefined behaviour! This is absoloutely *NOT* appropriate in this case, but I am including it for completeness `unsafe { std::hint::unreachable_unchecked() }`

You need to choose one of them and do it.

Comment: Thank you Plugwash, now I understand why is working in the full code version and why not in this little extract. In the full version it is inside of a loop, then if we go into the `Err` arm the error is handled with a `continue` to restart  the loop, I'm going to make some changes to improve the idiomatic and and for the code itself. I learned a lot, I will still studying, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check that a string represents a floating point value is to parse it, which your code is doing. Parsing user input by it's nature is fraught with error cases, so you inevitably have to perform a lot of error handling because Rust by it's design/nature forces you to handle errors.

The only real issue with your code is the compiler error you're getting. Your `let`...`match` arms are returning different types: `f64` and `()` (the unit struct), like the error message says. To fix this, return an f64 from the Err arm just like the Ok arm:

```rust
...
        Err(parse_float_error) => {
            println!("Please input a valid value. _{}_", parse_float_error);
            0.0f64
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't thinking about that it was returning two different kinds of value, to me the value in the `Err` arm it was irrelevant, because I wasn't expecting to do anything with it. I'm going to still studying 